# How to print sub matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Is there any short way in python to print sub matrix of a bigger matrix like this not using for loop?

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

sub1 = matrix[1:2][1:2] 
>>>desired answer: [[6,7][10,11]]
1   2  3   4
5  *6  7*  8 
9  *10 11* 12
13  14  15 16 

sub2 = matrix[2][1:3] 
>>>desired answer: [[7,11,15]]
1   2  3  4
5   6  *7* 8 
9  10 *11* 12
13 14 *15* 16
```

extra: for the latter example, how to return it in reverse format not using reverse()? ie: `[15,11,7]` or `[16,15,14]`,

Comment: He added the numpy tag and i consider numpy-arrays only (as i mentioned). But thanks anyway!

Comment: @sascha Oh, interesting point - I guess it's not clear if these are supposed to be numpy matrices or lists of lists.

Comment: Assuming numpy-arrays (you tagged it): If you would do sub1 = matrix[1:3,1:3] (bracketing!), you would achieve your desired answer! You know about python's slicing-style mimicked by numpy (inclusive, exclusive)? Example 2: matrix[1:4, 2]. (bracketing!) For list of lists (no numpy), look at Tom's answer! (readded this comment as there was a mistake and edit-time was over)

Comment: If you're using numpy, you'd do `matrix[1:3, 1:3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lists of lists, you can get your desired result like this:

```
>>> [s[1:3] for s in matrix[1:3]]
[[6, 7], [10, 11]]
>>>
>>> [s[2:3] for s in matrix[1:4]]
[[7], [11], [15]]
>>>
```

Note that the latter is a vertical slice, so each element is wrapped in its own list.  Also note that this is Python indexing, so the second limit in a range specifier is one higher than the last index in the slice.

Comment: thanks! working for me. would you provide numpy solution as well for further reference.

Comment: @DragonKnight numpy-solution is in the comments!

Comment: See the top-level comments for the numpy solutions - look at the comments by sascha and coldspeed.